SAML Single Logout
I am trying to find the session id in SAML response where salesforce is an identity provider. I expected it to be part of
<saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2024-11-12T19:58:23.003Z"
xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <saml2:AuthnContext>
        <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml2:AuthnContext>
</saml2:AuthnStatement>

I do not find it here. How do I find it ?
Session Id is needed for single logout. I wanted to see how it is passed in the login SAM response.

It's session index, not session id - doc has a good summary . In the initial SAML response, the session index parameter is sent if the connected app is configured for Single Logout. See SAML Profiles spec for more info.

Thanks for the correction. I had enabled the single logout for a different connected app :facepalm. I could now find the session index at AuthnStatement in the xml
